Language changes, but still the same locale on Android Kotlin
This is code from my ViewModelImplementation:
override fun openLanguageSelectionDialog(context: Context) {
        val items = arrayOf("rus", "kz")
        AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(context.getString(R.string.label_profile_dialog_language))
            .setItems(items) { _, which ->
                val selectedLanguage = when (which) {
                    0 -> "rus"
                    1 -> "kz"
                    else -> "ru" 
                }
                saveSelectedLanguage(selectedLanguage, context)
                changeLanguage(selectedLanguage, context)
            }
            .show()
    }

    private fun saveSelectedLanguage(language: String, context: Context) {
        val sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        with(sharedPrefs.edit()) {
            putString("selected_language", language)
            apply()
        }
    }
    private fun saveCurrentLocale(context: Context, locale: Locale) {
        val sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        with(sharedPrefs.edit()) {
            putString("current_locale", locale.language)
            apply()
        }
    }

    private fun getCurrentLocale(context: Context): Locale {
        val sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val language = sharedPrefs.getString("current_locale", "ru") /
        return Locale(language)
    }

    override fun changeLanguage(language: String, context: Context) {
            val config = context.resources.configuration
            val locale = when (language) {
                "Rus" -> Locale("ru")
                "Kz" -> Locale("kk")
                else -> Locale.getDefault() 
            }
            config.setLocale(locale)
            
            context.resources.updateConfiguration(config, context.resources.displayMetrics)
            context.recreate()
            saveCurrentLocale(context, locale)
           
    }

My language change after recreating activity, but not locale. I need locale changing for my dependencies with backend.
I need to change locale with my language after recreating activity. My project on MVVM architecture.
